# SPRING text context - AOP annotation

Tags: spring, junit, aop

I don't understand why my 2 tests the same AOP result. 
=> Test 1 call AOP (@After and @AfterThrowing) but Test 2. 
Can you help me ? I want to use spring inject directly without doing getBeans...

### Test class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/applicationcontext.xml" })
@TestExecutionListeners(listeners = {
    DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
    DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
    TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class })
@Component("Testing")
public class Testing {

private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(Testing.class);

@Autowired
ApplicationContext context;

@Test
public void testAOP() {
    logger.info("\n\n ********* test 1    // AOP");

    Testing testing = (Testing) context.getBean("Testing");
    logger.info("Object 1 = " + testing.toString());
    logger.info(testing.findBar());
}

@Test
public void testAOP2() {
    logger.info("\n\n ********* test 2    // AOP");

    logger.info("Object 2 = " + this.toString());
    logger.info(this.findBar());

}


public String findBar() {
    String tst = null;

    //LEVE ERRREUR
    if (tst.length() > 2)
        logger.error("Impossible");

    logger.error("Impossible");
    return "tst";
}
```

}

### ## ApplicationContext.xml ##

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util      http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd">



<!-- post-processors for all standard config annotations -->
<context:annotation-config />

<!-- List of packages containing Bean that uses Spring annotation -->
<context:component-scan base-package="fr" />

<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true" />

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:config.properties" />
```

--

### Results

```
INFO  - Could not instantiate TestExecutionListener org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener]. Specify custom listener classes or make the default listener classes (and their required dependencies) available. Offending class: [org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionAttributeSource]
INFO  - Using TestExecutionListeners
[org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@1ba9117e, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@732c2a62]
INFO  - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationcontext.xml]

INFO  - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@22ef9844: startup date [Tue Dec 22 19:53:41 CET 2015]; root of context hierarchy
INFO  - Loading properties file from class path resource [config.properties]
INFO  - @After
INFO  - 
********* test 1    // AOP
INFO  - @After
INFO  - Object 1 = fr.tests.Testing@4248ed58
INFO  - @After
INFO  -  ************* @AfterThrowing   ************ 
INFO  - 
********* test 2    // AOP
INFO  - Object 2 = fr.tests.Testing@faa3fed
INFO  - Closing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@22ef9844: startup date [Tue Dec 22 19:53:41 CET 2015]; root of context hierarchy
```

Comment: Spring AOP uses proxies and will only proxy beans in the context, your test case isn't a spring bean hence no AOP.

Comment: I had in application context
`code`   
  <bean id="Testing" class="fr.tests.Testing"/>
   <bean id="aopLog" class="fr.tests.AopLog"/> 
`code`

but Test2 does't do AOP . How can I say my test case is a spring bean ?

Comment: That still doesn't make your test a spring bean, it never will be a spring managed bean. JUnit and not spring is in control and that will not change. If you want to apply AOP to your testcase as well you would need to use compile time AOP and not springs proxy based AOP.